# Document.write won't display what I want

Tags: javascript

so I made a Function:

```
function dw (wrtext){
  document.write(wrtext)
}
```

And then this :

```
function creditos(){
  dw('<p style="font-family: Arial; font-size: 15pt; font-weight: bold; text-align: left;">------------------------------------------------</p>')
  dw('<p style="font-family: Arial; font-size: 15pt; font-weight: bold; text-align: left;"> Preço Certo</p>')
  dw('<p style="font-family: Arial; font-size: 15pt; font-weight: bold; text-align: left;"> ------------------------------------------------</p>')
  dw('<p style="font-family: Arial; font-size: 15pt; font-weight: bold; text-align: left;"> 1- 1º Jogo</p>')
  dw('<p style="font-family: Arial; font-size: 15pt; font-weight: bold; text-align: left;"> 2- 2º Jogo</p>')
  dw('<p style="font-family: Arial; font-size: 15pt; font-weight: bold; text-align: left;"> 3- 3º Jogo</p>')
  dw('<p style="font-family: Arial; font-size: 15pt; font-weight: bold; text-align: left;"> 4- Vencedor</p>')
  dw('<p style="font-family: Arial; font-size: 15pt; font-weight: bold; text-align: left;"> 5- Créditos</p>')
  dw('<p style="font-family: Arial; font-size: 15pt; font-weight: bold; text-align: left;"> 0- Terminar</p>')
  dw('<p style="font-family: Arial; font-size: 15pt; font-weight: bold; text-align: right; margin-top: -300px"> Trabalho: Preço Certo</p>')
  dw('<p style="font-family: Arial; font-size: 15pt; font-weight: bold; text-align: right; margin-top: -300px"> Realização por: Duarte Nuno de Brito Arribas, Nº 07, 10º M;</p>')
  dw('<p style="font-family: Arial; font-size: 15pt; font-weight: bold; text-align: right; margin-top: -300px"> Escola Secundária Quinta das Palmeiras;</p>')
  dw('<p style="font-family: Arial; font-size: 15pt; font-weight: bold; text-align: right; margin-top: -300px"> Curso Profissional Técnico de Multimédia;</p>')
  dw('<p style="font-family: Arial; font-size: 15pt; font-weight: bold; text-align: right; margin-top: -300px"> Disciplina: Sistemas de Informação (S.I.);</p>')
  dw('<p style="font-family: Arial; font-size: 15pt; font-weight: bold; text-align: right; margin-top: -300px"> Módulo 3: Introdução à programação;</p>')
  dw('<p style="font-family: Arial; font-size: 15pt; font-weight: bold; text-align: right; margin-top: -300px"> Ano letivo: 2016-2017;</p>')
}
```

Just a bunch of words with styles, but for some reason it won't display many of them, with the exception of the second one.

Any Help would be appreciated!!!

Cheers and Thanks in Advance!!!

Comment: Join the 21st century and stop using `document.write()`.

Comment: And end your statements with semicolon. Many errors are caused by misunderstanding of automatic semicolon insertion.

Comment: your margin-top is -300 on a lot of them.  If you change it to positive 300 you should see them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some pieces of advice, if I may...

1. Do not use `document.write`. It is outdated and is now a bad practice.
2. Do not repeat yourself (these `dw` calls are awful).
3. Do not mix HTML with CSS. Avoid the `style` attribute.
4. Learn and use ES6 features if you can.

With a bit of refactoring, your code could be much more readable:

```js
function creditos() {
  document.body.innerHTML = `
    <div class="left">
      ------------------------------------------------<br>
      Preço Certo<br>
      ------------------------------------------------<br>
      <ol>
        <li>1º Jogo</li>
        <li>2º Jogo</li>
        <li>3º Jogo</li>
        <li>Vencedor</li>
        <li>Créditos</li>
        <li>Terminar</li>
      </ol>
    </div>
    <address class="right">
      Trabalho: Preço Certo<br>
      Realização por: Duarte Nuno de Brito Arribas, Nº 07, 10º M;<br>
      Escola Secundária Quinta das Palmeiras;<br>
      Curso Profissional Técnico de Multimédia;<br>
      Disciplina: Sistemas de Informação (S.I.);<br>
      Módulo 3: Introdução à programação;<br>
      Ano letivo: 2016-2017;<br>
    </address>`;
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => creditos());
```

```css
p {
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 15pt;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.left {
  text-align: left;
}

.right {
  text-align: right;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This will not work unless you combine all strings into one string, and then write it all at once.

If you take a look at the documentation here: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_doc_write.asp

document.write will delete all existing html which is why your code is breaking.

Here is a jsfiddle demonstrating it working with all the text combined as one, and then using a single document.write:

https://jsfiddle.net/uch4mxba/

```
alltext = "";
function dw (wrtext){
  alltext = alltext + wrtext;
}
function creditos(){
  dw('<p style="font-family: Arial; font-size: 15pt; font-weight: bold; text-align: left;">------------------------------------------------</p>')
  dw('<p style="font-family: Arial; font-size: 15pt; font-weight: bold; text-align: left;"> Preço Certo</p>')
  dw('<p style="font-family: Arial; font-size: 15pt; font-weight: bold; text-align: left;"> ------------------------------------------------</p>')
  dw('<p style="font-family: Arial; font-size: 15pt; font-weight: bold; text-align: left;"> 1- 1º Jogo</p>')
  dw('<p style="font-family: Arial; font-size: 15pt; font-weight: bold; text-align: left;"> 2- 2º Jogo</p>')
  dw('<p style="font-family: Arial; font-size: 15pt; font-weight: bold; text-align: left;"> 3- 3º Jogo</p>')
  dw('<p style="font-family: Arial; font-size: 15pt; font-weight: bold; text-align: left;"> 4- Vencedor</p>')
  dw('<p style="font-family: Arial; font-size: 15pt; font-weight: bold; text-align: left;"> 5- Créditos</p>')
  dw('<p style="font-family: Arial; font-size: 15pt; font-weight: bold; text-align: left;"> 0- Terminar</p>')
  dw('<p style="font-family: Arial; font-size: 15pt; font-weight: bold; text-align: right; margin-top: -300px"> Trabalho: Preço Certo</p>')
  dw('<p style="font-family: Arial; font-size: 15pt; font-weight: bold; text-align: right; margin-top: -300px"> Realização por: Duarte Nuno de Brito Arribas, Nº 07, 10º M;</p>')
  dw('<p style="font-family: Arial; font-size: 15pt; font-weight: bold; text-align: right; margin-top: -300px"> Escola Secundária Quinta das Palmeiras;</p>')
  dw('<p style="font-family: Arial; font-size: 15pt; font-weight: bold; text-align: right; margin-top: -300px"> Curso Profissional Técnico de Multimédia;</p>')
  dw('<p style="font-family: Arial; font-size: 15pt; font-weight: bold; text-align: right; margin-top: -300px"> Disciplina: Sistemas de Informação (S.I.);</p>')
  dw('<p style="font-family: Arial; font-size: 15pt; font-weight: bold; text-align: right; margin-top: -300px"> Módulo 3: Introdução à programação;</p>')
  dw('<p style="font-family: Arial; font-size: 15pt; font-weight: bold; text-align: right; margin-top: -300px"> Ano letivo: 2016-2017;</p>')
}
creditos();
document.write(alltext);
```

I would urge you to not do this at all, why not write all of this html into an html file instead of using document.write to build it in javascript? Just a suggestion. Good luck.